# Glyphicon and Font Awesome displaying box with a question mark

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, glyphicons

Basically what the Title says, my Website isn't displaying the Glyphicons neither the Font Awesome Icons, once I enter the Code, this is what comes out: http://prntscr.com/8qwwmd for the Glyphicon and Font Awesome Icons. This issue actually never happened to me before and this didn't affect all of my Sites in localhost.

Comment: Can you see the resources being loaded as expected?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: My crystal ball says that your file paths are incorrect.

Comment: Everything seems to load as expected. and here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/sddbroLn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the javascript console and see if you're getting any 404 errors for missing resources. It depends on how you're loading font awesome or glyphicon libraries and whether or not they are visible from your file.

I assume you know how to check the console, if not, generally speaking:

- Right click
- Inspect element
- Click the tab that says "console"
- Reload the page

If no errors are found here, maybe network errors are disabled, in which case:

- Right click
- Inspect element
- Click the tab that says "network"
- Reload the page

In the case that a 404 is not your issue, make sure that the respective CSS libraries are properly included. If none of this works, then please provide more information as to what is happening.

**EDIT**

So, given your comment and checking out your JSFiddle I figured out what the problem is. All of your assets are loading correctly, but you happen to have a bad CSS rule that is messing up your code:

```
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
```

This rule overwrites whatever bootstrap's default font on it's glyphicon class is, which messes up your code. Removing the "!important" makes it work, which I would suggest doing because you don't want to be using !important on a global css selector.

```
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
```

Comment: Here's what comes in the Network Error: http://prntscr.com/8qxeji

Comment: Check out my updated answer for the solution.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you very much. just a simple change.. huh (what an idiot I am). Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer as correct if you feel that it is :)